# "Мотивация, как потребность к созданию (в создании) красоты" — как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, управление

Может, есть другие варианты, чтобы выразить мысль?

Comment: Представление о контексте было бы уместно: варианты будут меньшим числом, но качественней.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша мысль мне не понятна. Мотивация — совокупность мотивов (причин, оснований, поводов), движущих человеком  в его поступках. Я бы не стал рассматривать мотивацию как потребность. Но можно сказать, что та или иная потребность служит мотивацией той или иной активности.

Потребность в чем-либо, а не к чему-либо:  **потребность в создании красоты**.

Как вариант:

**Потребность в создании красоты служила мотивацией его товорчества.**

Answer (score 0):

**Мотивация (деятельности человека) как потребность к созданию прекрасного (красоты).**

**Как выбрать предлог?**

Прекрасное ― это **потребность для человека.** В человеке пробуждается **потребность  к созданию прекрасного**. Он чувствует  **потребность в прекрасном.**

Из словаря:
**МОТИВ**,  побудительная причина, основание, повод к какому-л. действию, поступку.
**МОТИВАЦИЯ**, совокупность мотивов, доводов для обоснования чего-л.
**ПОТРЕБНОСТЬ,** -и; ж. Надобность, нужда в чём-л., требующая удовлетворения. Материальные, духовные потребности человека.

Деятельность людей **мотивирована** и связана с  их **потребностями.** Потребность в определенной деятельности можно определить как мотивацию этой деятельности.
Статья по теме  https://studopedia.su/12_63367_motivatsiya-potrebnostey.html

**Примеры с разными предлогами**:

2200 примеров (часто материального характера):
И когда наша **потребность в такой свободе** ― свободе от самих себя ― сталкивается с путешествием, то мы способны полюбить этот город, полюбить его за то, что ему ничего от нас не надо, полюбить его безразличие.

43 примера:
Человек начинает быть другим. В нем пробуждается **потребность к самосовершенствованию.**

13 примеров:
Искусство есть такая же **потребность для человека**, как есть и пить. [Н. К. Рерих. Листы дневника (1942)]

Comment: По поводу предлога К я, признаться, сконфужен. Словарь управления не дает К (ПОТРЕБНОСТЬ в ком-чём / чего). "Потребность К" я считал ошибкой (корректно: стремление К). Но в Нацкорпусе нашел. А как же словари?

Comment: По поводу мотивации и потребности. По моему, это отношения общего понятия (мотиваця) и частного (потребность). Я уж не говорю о том, что мотивация — это *совокупность* мотивов. МОТИВЦИЯ, Совокупность мотивов. Возьмем один мотив ( мотив = побудительная причина).  Можно сказать "потребность в прекрасном как побудительная причина", но нельзя сказать "побудительная причина как потребность в прекрасном".

Comment: Обычно на  поступки человека влияет несколько причин, тут одним мотивом на обойдешься. К примеру, если вы захотите бросить всё и уехать на Гаити рисовать картины,  то для этого нужна  мотивация в виде целого ряда причин и доводов. Потребность в прекрасном можно удовлетворить, сходив в музей или повесив на стену картину, другое дело - потребность в создании  предметов искусства.

Comment: По поводу союза К. В словарной статье потребность дополнительно обозначена как желание, стремление,  отсюда следует стремление/ потребность к творчеству.

Comment: Если стремление и потребность синонимы, значит ли это, что управление то же у обоих, вопреки словарю управления? Или это ошибочное перенесение управления с одного синонима на другой?

Comment: Думаю, что управление у синонимов разное, но какое-то взаимное влияние возможно, например по схеме: "потребность (какая?) стремиться к творчеству"  переходит в "потребность к творчеству".