# Корректно ли писать: "Потребность к (чему-либо)"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, управление

Корректно ли писать: "потребность к чему-либо"? Эта тема обсуждалась в комментариях [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/438281/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B), но я думаю, она заслуживает отдельного вопроса.

> [Управление в русском языке](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C):
> ПОТРЕБНОСТЬ в ком-чём / чего. Потребность в сотрудниках; Потребности тяжёлой промышленности в каменном угле; Потребность растений в воде; Потребность в человеческой ласке; Ограничивать все потребности семейства до крайности.

Как видим, в словаре осутствует *потребность к чему*. Однако есть немало  примеров употребления слова *потребность* с последующим предлогом *к*, в том числе десятки вхождений в Нацкорпусе, например:

> Какое отношение воспитание патриотизма и развитие внутренней **потребности к самосовершенствованию** может иметь к преступлению, над которым ломал голову Гена Колосенцев? [Александра Маринина. Последний рассвет (2013)]
>
> Это ядро, ответственное за человеческую **потребность к познанию**, сохраняется постоянно и готово к активизации. [Эрик Галимов. По поводу конца науки // «Знание - сила», 2009]
>
> Сегодня, когда Россия, как государство новой формации, перешла в стадию рыночных отношений, предприимчивые и крайне неравнодушные к деньгам люди смекнули, что раз есть у населения **потребность к изучению боевых искусств**, то почему бы этим не воспользоваться. [Максим Кастет. Система рукопашного боя «Стальной волк» (2004) // «Боевое искусство планеты», 2004.06.10]

Мне кажется, имеет место смешение двух понятий: "потребность в" и "стремление к". Поскольку потребность и стремление — синонимы, происходит ошибочное перенесение управления с одного синонима на другой.

Мнение Jasmin: *Думаю, что управление у синонимов разное, но какое-то взаимное влияние возможно, например по схеме: "потребность (какая?) стремиться к творчеству" переходит в "потребность к творчеству".*

Хотелось бы знать, есть ли другие источники, объясняющие (обосновывающие) употребления слова *потребность* с последующим предлогом *к*.

Comment: Здесь подборка статей о _потребностях и мотивации_: http://www.pragmatist.ru/motivaciya-truda/teoriya-ierarxii-potrebnostej-a-maslou.html Не все просмотрел, но пока "вольностей" не встретилось (слово _потребности_ множество раз употреблено). Есть разве что _от одного уровня **потребностей к** другому_.

Comment: à propos, посмотрел Розенталь "Пунктуация и управление в РЯ" (1988 г.). Там кроме формы с "в" даётся и форма без предлога: Потребность человеческой ласки (в человеческой ласке).

Answer (score 2):

Сочетание с предлогом возможно, но не в форме "иметь потребность к чему". Можно упомянуть о потребности кого-то в чём-то, а затем отнести эту потребность к чему-нибудь:

> У части населения сохраняется потребность в табаке; принято относить
>   такую **потребность к** вредным/дурным привычкам.

Приведённые в вопросе примеры я отношу к ошибкам корректоров. Ранее приводившаяся статистика успокаивает, что до включения такой мутации в норму далеко. Не думаю, что можно напр. *проявить потребность к творчеству*, а чего нельзя проявить, того и нет.

Answer (score 2):

Я согласен в целом с мнением **Jasmin**, которое приведено в вопросе. В тех случаях, когда выражение **потребность к** встречается в авторитетных источниках, оно означает примерно следующее: "стремление на уровне жизненно важной потребности". И заменить это выражение каким-то другим в том же контексте в некоторых случаях было бы весьма сложно.

Я не могу поверить, чтобы те тысячи случаев употребления выражения **потребность к**, которые находит Google.books были все результатом ошибок корректоров. Каждый может потратить немного времени, углубившись в результаты [этого поиска](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b&biw=1047&bih=456&tbm=bks&ei=Lu-oWuXDNs21kwXOyqXADw&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BA%22&oq=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BA%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...0.0.0.813366.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.ewuwL8cOv3g), чтобы обнаружить там порядка 10% случаев, которые не должны вызывать сомнений в качестве изданий.

> *От   родителей  он унаследовал жажду скитаний, лихорадочную потребность к движению и стремление во всем испить чашу до дна.*
>   ("Дочь снегов", Джек Лондон, изд-во "Правда", М. 1976)

Или вот цитата из Л.Н. Толстого в "**Справочнике издателя и автора**" А.Э. Мильчина со ссылкой на собрание сочинений в 22-х томах (М. 1983):

> *...Образование есть деятельность человека, имеющая своим основанием
>   потребность к равенству ...*

У Льва Николаевича "потребность к" встречается не так уж редко.

Наибольший процент обнаруженных цитат приходится на учебники и специализированную литературу по педагогическим и общественным наукам. Но я думаю, что это специфика Google.books, а не реальные пропорции.

Comment: Для чистоты эксперимента добавим, что "потребность в" дает 178 000 результатов ("потребность к" - 9900). И для большей иллюстративности приведем ссылку на Корпус ВИМРЯ http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EF%EE%F2%F0%E5%E1%ED%EE%F1%F2%FC+%EA

Comment: Вопрос был не о том, какой предлог встречается чаще. Более того, большинство случаев употребления "потребность к", которые находит Google.books, я сам счёл бы сомнительным.

Comment: Согласен, источники там сомнительные (я склоняюсь, что причин много: неграмотность, спешка и т.п.). Формально (по современным правилам) они ошибаются (возможно, при Толстом это было более распространено и в то время не считалось ошибкой, надо проверять). В Корпусе источники, на первый взгляд, поинтереснее, там тоже что-то видно, но надо анализировать.

Comment: Не знаю, с чем Вы согласны, но я вижу большое количество источников, которые у меня не вызывают сомнений. Мне просто лень выписывать десятки цитат (их можно найти по приведенной ссылке), а Л.Н. Толстого я привёл только ради А.Э. Мильчина. Или для Вас это тоже сомнительный источник?

Comment: "Более того, большинство случаев употребления "потребность к", которые находит Google.books, я сам счёл бы сомнительным" - согласен с этим. Корректность Толстого у меня сомнений не вызывает (предполагаю, что 100-120 лет назад это могло быть и нормой).

Comment: Я высказал своё отношение к вопросу в ответах и комментариях выше. Дайте, пожалуйста, свой ответ — я не могу начинать всё повторять по новому кругу. Если когда-то раньше это было нормой, то где-то должно быть сказано, что это норма отменена или изменилась. Было бы замечательно, если бы Вы нашли эту информацию. А просто "сомнения в виде версий" меня меньше интересуют.

Comment: grizzly, мне Ваш ответ нравится. Думаю, нет смысла давать другой. Первые комментарии дал для уточнения и полноты информации (как принцип комментариев на stackexchange). Результаты Корпуса (хотя там всего 40 документов, среди них Толстой, Чайковский, Станиславский) подтверждают Вашу версию и дополняют поиск GoogleBooks (в который включены в т.ч. и сомнительные книги). Т.о., я с Вашей версией согласен (возможность сознательного авторского узуса) и не вижу смысла писать ответ, надеясь что автор вопроса и прочие увидят приведенные ссылки. Насчет нормы 19 века данных нет, поэтому и не настаивал.